# How can I draw vertical lines?

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

[image]

how can I draw a vertical line for each date

y-axis works well but why not x-axis?

code for x-axis:

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 2;
majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor redColor];

CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;

CPTXYAxis *x = [axisSet xAxis];
x.axisLineStyle = nil;
x.majorTickLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;

[x setLabelingPolicy:CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone];
x.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;

NSArray *subjectsArray = [self getSubjectTitlesAsArray];
[x setAxisLabels:[NSSet setWithArray:subjectsArray]];
```

code for y-axis:

```
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.axisLineStyle = nil;
y.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
y.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"500");
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");

y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
```

what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Plot will draw grid lines at the major tick locations. Make sure the date values correspond with the tick locations and `gridLineStyle` is a style that will appear against the white background.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Eric !

for sure, there are some more elegant ways to code it, but I solved it like this:

```
    NSMutableSet *xMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:6.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:7.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:9.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:11.0f]];
[xMajorLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.0f]];

x.majorTickLocations = xMajorLocations;
```

[image]